# Linked List insertion isn't working in for/while loop

Tags: c++, oop, linked-list

I am learning DSA, and was trying to implement linked list but the insertion function that i wrote is not
working in a for or while loop, its not the same when i call that function outside the loop, it works that way. I am not able to figure it out, please someone help me.

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {

public:
  int data;
  Node *next;

  Node(int &num) {
    this->data = num;
    next = NULL;
  }
};

class LinkedList {

  Node *head = NULL;

public:
  void insert(int num) {
    Node *tmp;
    if (head == NULL) {
      head = new Node(num);
      tmp = head;
    } else {
      tmp->next = new Node(num);
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
  }

  void printList() {
    Node *tmp = head;
    while (tmp) {
      std::cout << tmp->data << "  ";
      tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  void reverseList() {
    Node *curr = head, *prev = NULL, *nextNode;
    while (curr) {
      nextNode = curr->next;
      curr->next = prev;
      prev = curr;
      curr = nextNode;
    }
    head = prev;
  }
};

int main() {
  LinkedList list1;
  // This is not working
  int num;
  while (num != -1) {
    std::cin >> num;
    list1.insert(num);
  }

  // This is working
  // list1.insert(1);
  // list1.insert(2);
  // list1.insert(3);
  // list1.insert(4);
  // list1.insert(5);

  list1.printList();
  list1.reverseList();
  list1.printList();

  return 0;
}
```

[I expect this after insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZsOj.png)

Edit:
although @Roberto Montalti solved this for me, but before that I tried passing incrementing value using a for loop which worked but as soon as I pull that **cin** out it crashes. can someone tell me what's happening under the hood?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    list1.insert(i);
}
```

Comment: Insert works the first time, when head is NULL, but when you enter the else-part it uses `tmp->next` when `tmp` has no value. It doesn't remember a value from the previous call, but starts  all over for each call.

Comment: It doesn't work in either scenario (in the loop or outside of it). It just doesn't happen to crash in the latter. If your insert method is designed to add the new node at the head of the list (as opposed to the tail), then allocate the new node, set its next pointer to head, then set head to the new node.

Comment: @jarmod no no insert() is supposed to add a new node after head. also I tried printing head before and after reversing and it was all okay, inserted 1,2,3,4,5 head was 1, after reverse() head was 5. one more thing I tried was, I inserted 0-10 digits using a for loop (i = 0 to i <= 10) and that also worked. so I guess the problem occurs when I take input and then pass it to insert()

Comment: I think you mean it should be added at the tail of the list, not "after the head", which is ambiguous. If that's what you want then either maintain a tail pointer or iterate from head till you find the tail. Regarding your "it worked" comment - C programs often *appear* to work correctly but still have major bugs (as your code does). Your code invokes undefined behavior, which includes the possibility that it will not appear to fail (by chance, depending on the environment it runs in).

Comment: @jarmod oh yes at the tail, my bad. Also I agreed with what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inserting the nth item (1st excluded) tmp is a null pointer, i don't understand what you are doing there, you are assigning to `next` of some memory then you make that pointer point to another location, losing the pointer next you assigned before, you must keep track of the last item if you want optimal insertion. This way you are only assigning to some *tmp then going out of scope loses all your data... The best way is to just keep a pointer to the last inserted item, no need to use *tmp.

```cpp
class LinkedList
{
   Node *head = NULL;
   Node *tail = NULL;

public:
    void insert(int num)
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = new Node(num);
            tail = head;
        }
        else
        {
            tail->next = new Node(num);
            tail = tail->next;
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: whoa thanks for this quick reply! its working now! but one question I would like to ask, why the program wasn't crashing when I was calling insert() manually like line by line.

Comment: crashing is one possibile outcome of undefined behavior, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: This question is really interesting, I tried it myself and surprisingly you are right! I made the insert function print the `tmp` pointer right after the declaration, and without a loop going on, `tmp` is set to the value assigned in the previous call... I think the compiler here is doing some sort of magic since it knows how many times you are calling insert it can simply declare `tmp` one time and run five times the remaining code with the values you supplied manually. However, this won't work in a loop because the compiler can't know how many times you are going to call insert().

Comment: To test this out you can force the compiler to declare the `tmp` pointer only once by placing `static Node *tmp;` in your old implementation of insert, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @RobertoMontalti Yeah I tried changing `Node *tmp` to `static Node *tmp` as you said , it was getting created only once and everything worked fine. Now I understand in loop `tmp` will get created multiple times and that's why program was crashing. I was thinking it has something to do with taking input or something but you cleared that doubt, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop until you reach the end of the list and then add the new node after that. Like this.

```
void insert(int num) {
    Node *tmp = head;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = new Node(num);
    }
    else {
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = new Node(num);
    }
  }
```

Comment: But this will take more time for insertion, am I right?

Comment: Not too much. That depends on how long your linked list is but the insertion part shouldn't take much time at this level.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you need to define a node for each of the tail and head of the list as follows

```
Node *h;
Node *t;
```

you may also separate the Node from the LinkedList class so you can modify easily

```
class Node{
public:
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int data, Node* next);
    ~Node();
};
Node::Node(int data, Node* next)
{
    this->data= data;
    this->next= next;
}
Node::~Node(){}
}
```

after that you can try to add these functions to your LinkedList class
so it can deal with other special cases such empty list or full, etc..

```
void addToHead(int data){
Node *x = new Node(data,h);
    h=x;
    if(t==NULL){
        t=x;
    }


void addToTail(int data){
Node *x = new Node(data,NULL);
    if(isEmpty()){
        h=t=x;
    }
    else
    {
        t->next=x;
        t=x;
    }
}
```

now for the insert function try this after you implemented the Node class and the other functions,

```
void insert(int v){
if(h==nullptr){addToHead(v); return;}
if(h->data>=v) {addToHead(v);return;}
if(t->data<=v) {addToTail(v); return;}
// In this case there is at least two nodes
Node *k=h->next;
Node *p=h;

while(k != nullptr){
if(k->data >v){
Node *z =new Node(v,k);
p->next=z;
return;
}
p=k;
k=k->next;
}

}
```

the idea of making all of this is not lose the pointer when it goes through elements in the Linked List so you don't end up with a run time error.

I hope this can be useful to you.

Comment: Yes it's definitely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with your insert function.
Read about segmentation fault here [https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/core-dump-segmentation-fault-c-cpp/#:~:text=Core%20Dump%2FSegmentation%20fault%20is,is%20known%20as%20core%20dump](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/core-dump-segmentation-fault-c-cpp/#:%7E:text=Core%20Dump%2FSegmentation%20fault%20is,is%20known%20as%20core%20dump).

for a quick workaround you can use this

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
    class Node
    {
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node(int num)
        {
            this->data = num;
            next = NULL;
        }
    };
    
    class LinkedList
    {
    Node *head = NULL;
    
    public:
        void insert(int num)
        {
            Node *tmp= new Node(num);
            tmp->next=head;
            head=tmp;
        }
        void printList()
        {
            Node *tmp = head;
            while (tmp)
            {
                std::cout << tmp->data << "  ";
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        void reverseList()
        {
            Node *curr = head, *prev = NULL, *nextNode;
            while (curr)
            {
                nextNode = curr->next;
                curr->next = prev;
                prev = curr;
                curr = nextNode;
            }
            head = prev;
        }
    };
    
    int main()
    {
        LinkedList list1;
        // This is not working
        int num,i=0,n;
        cout<<"Type the value of n";
        cin>>n;
        while (i<n)
        {
            cin >> num;
            cout<<num<<" "<<&num<<endl;
            list1.insert(num);
            i++;
        }

    
        list1.printList();
        list1.reverseList();
        list1.printList();
    
        return 0;
    }
```